# Searching for equivalent of FileNotFoundError in Python 2

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, file, exception

I created a class named Options. It works fine but not not with Python 2.
And I want it to work on both Python 2 and 3.
The problem is identified: FileNotFoundError doesn t exist in Python 2.
But if I use IOError it doesn t work in Python 3

Changed in version 3.3: EnvironmentError, IOError, WindowsError, VMSError, socket.error, select.error and mmap.error have been merged into OSError.

What should I do ???(Please do not discuss my choice of portability, I have reasons.)

Here s the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
#-*-coding:utf-8*

#option_controller.py

#Walle Cyril
#25/01/2014

import json
import os

class Options():
    """Options is a class designed to read, add and change informations in a JSON file with a dictionnary in it.

    The entire object works even if the file is missing since it re-creates it.
    If present it must respect the JSON format: e.g. keys must be strings and so on.
    If something corrupted the file, just destroy the file or call read_file method to remake it."""

    def __init__(self,directory_name="Cache",file_name="options.json",imported_default_values=None):
        #json file
        self.option_file_path=os.path.join(directory_name,file_name)
        self.directory_name=directory_name
        self.file_name=file_name
        #self.parameters_json_file={'sort_keys':True, 'indent':4, 'separators':(',',':')}
        #the default data
        if imported_default_values is None:
            DEFAULT_INDENT = 2
            self.default_values={\
                "translate_html_level": 1,\
                "indent_size":DEFAULT_INDENT,\
                "document_title":"Titre"}
        else:
            self.default_values=imported_default_values


    def read_file(self,read_this_key_only=False):
        """returns the value for the given key or a dictionary if the key is not given.

        returns None if it s impossible"""
        try:
            text_in_file=open(self.option_file_path,'r').read()
        except FileNotFoundError:#not 2.X compatible
            text_in_file=""#if the file is not there we re-make one with default values
        if text_in_file=="":#same if the file is empty
            self.__insert_all_default_values()
            text_in_file=open(self.option_file_path,'r').read()

        try:
            option_dict=json.loads(text_in_file)
        except ValueError:
            #if the json file is broken we re-make one with default values
            self.__insert_all_default_values()
            text_in_file=open(self.option_file_path,'r').read()
            option_dict=json.loads(text_in_file)

        if read_this_key_only:
            if read_this_key_only in option_dict:
                return option_dict[read_this_key_only]#
            else:
                #if the value is not there it should be written for the next time
                if read_this_key_only in self.default_values:
                    self.add_option_to_file(read_this_key_only,self.default_values[read_this_key_only])
                    return self.default_values[read_this_key_only]
                else:
                    #impossible because there is not default value so the value isn t meant to be here
                    return None
        else:
            return option_dict

    def add_option_to_file(self,key,value):#or update
        """Adds or updates an option(key and value) to the json file if the option exists in the default_values of the object."""

        option_dict=self.read_file()
        if key in self.default_values:
            option_dict[key]=value
        open(self.option_file_path,'w').write(\
            json.dumps(option_dict,sort_keys=True, indent=4, separators=(',',':')))


    def __insert_all_default_values(self):
        """Recreate json file with default values.

    called if the document is empty or non-existing or corrupted."""
        try:
            open(self.option_file_path,'w').write(\
            json.dumps(self.default_values,sort_keys=True, indent=4, separators=(',',':')))
        except FileNotFoundError:
            os.mkdir(self.directory_name)#Create the directory
            if os.path.isdir(self.directory_name):#succes
                self.__insert_all_default_values()
            else:
                print("Impossible to write in %s and file %s not found" % (os.getcwd(),self.option_file_path))


#demo
if __name__ == '__main__':

    option_file_object=Options()
    print(option_file_object.__doc__)
    print(option_file_object.read_file())
    option_file_object.add_option_to_file("","test")#this should have no effect

    option_file_object.add_option_to_file("translate_html_level","0")#this should have an effect
    print("value of translate_html_level:",option_file_object.read_file("translate_html_level"))
    print(option_file_object.read_file())
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can use the base class exception [EnvironmentError](http://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html#exceptions.EnvironmentError) and use the 'errno' attribute to figure out which exception was raised:

```
from __future__ import print_function

import os
import errno

try:
    open('no file of this name')   # generate 'file not found error'
except EnvironmentError as e:      # OSError or IOError...
    print(os.strerror(e.errno))
```

Or just use IOError in the same way:

```
try:
    open('/Users/test/Documents/test')   # will be a permission error
except IOError as e:
    print(os.strerror(e.errno))
```

That works on Python 2 or Python 3.

Be careful not to compare against number values directly, because they [can be different](http://www.ioplex.com/~miallen/errcmpp.html) on different platforms. Instead, use the named constants in [Python's standard library `errno` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/errno.html) which will use the correct values for the run-time platform.

Comment: I would recommend using `EnvironmentError` over `IOError`.  Here's why: On Python2.7, some operations (such as `os.remove`) raise `WindowsError`, a type of `OSError` (not an `IOError`).  In Python 2.7, both `OSError` and `IOError` inherit from `EnvironmentError`, and in and in Python 3.3+, `EnvironmentError` is an alias for `OSError`.  In Python 3, `FileNotFoundError` inherits from `OSError` (a.k.a. `EnvironmentError`).  So, `EnvironmentError` should cover all bases.  Use `EnvironmentError`.

Answer (score 52):

If `FileNotFoundError` isn't there, define it:

```
try:
    FileNotFoundError
except NameError:
    FileNotFoundError = IOError
```

Now you can catch `FileNotFoundError` in Python 2 since it's really `IOError`.

Be careful though, `IOError` has other meanings. In particular, any message should probably say "file could not be read" rather than "file not found."

Comment: Nice solution. Since I am making use of `six`, I did:

`if six.PY2: FileNotFoundError = IOError`

Comment: If you want to except only 'file not found' errors see my solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/55755432/7830612

Comment: `os.remove("fake_file")` in Python 2.7.17 raises `WindowsError`, which inherits from `OSError`, not `IOError`.

Answer (score 8):

The Python 2 / 3 compatible way to except a `FileNotFoundError` is this:

```
import errno

try:
    with open('some_file_that_does_not_exist', 'r'):
        pass
except EnvironmentError as e:
    if e.errno != errno.ENOENT:
        raise
```

Other answers are close, but don't re-raise if the error number doesn't match.

Using `IOError` is fine for most cases, but for some reason `os.listdir()` and friends raise `OSError` instead on Python 2. <strike>Since `IOError` inherits from `OSError` it's fine to just always catch `OSError` and check the error number.</strike>

Edit: The previous sentence is only true on Python 3. To be cross compatible, instead catch `EnvironmentError` and check the error number.

Comment: Does `IOError` inherit from `OSError`? it doesn't for me on Python 2.7.16 on macOS. Instead, they each inherit from `EnvironmentError`.

Comment: @Jason R. Coombs I just tested this again on Python 2.7.10 and it looks like you're correct. I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 2):

For what it's worth, although the `IOError` is hardly mentioned in [Python 3's official document](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html) and does not even showed up in [its official Exception hierarchy](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#exception-hierarchy), it is still there, and it is the parent class of `FileNotFoundError` in Python 3. See `python3 -c "print(isinstance(FileNotFoundError(), IOError))"` giving you a `True`. Therefore, you can technically write your code in this way, which works for both Python 2 and Python 3.

```
try: 
    content = open("somefile.txt").read()
except IOError:  # Works in both Python 2 & 3
    print("Oops, we can not read this file")
```

It might be "good enough" in many cases. Although in general, it is not recommended to rely on an undocumented behavior. So, I'm not really suggesting this approach. I personally use [Kindall's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21368622/728675).

Comment: `IOerror` is not ideal because `os.listdir()` raises an `OSError` on Python 2, but `FileNotFoundError` on Python 3.