# python 2.x:Conditionally Catching Exceptions (Ignore gracefully cleanup if the file is missing)

Tags: python, exception, python-2.x

I am having a script which cleanups the logs older than 14 days at a shared location. Now this script can run at same time from different host. In a particular situation if two or more hosts try to cleanup same file, only one will succeed and all other gives error "No such file or directory". How can I update the code to Ignore gracefully cleanup if the file suddenly goes missing. Below is part of code which is performing the cleanup. `count` tracks the number of files deleted.

```
if os.stat(filename).st_mtime < current_time - 14 * 86400:
    try:
       os.remove(filename)
       count += 1
    except:
       logger.warning("Not able to delete the file %s" % filename)
```

One way is to "pass" the exception if file dont exist but continue to log warning if you are not able to delete the file. How to include this condition.

Comment: I imagine an exception is raised at `os.stat()`? If so, you could just move that into the try-except. Alternatively, you could check if the file exists beforehand using `os.path.exists`.

Comment: @Mark what if two hosts pass the if loop that file exists and both attempt to delete it?

Comment: Yup, that's a good point. So the best course of action is to catch the exceptions using try-except.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Mark suggests you could check beforehand if the file exists and then delete it but there is still a potential race condition in such an approach. It can occur between script's instances after `os.stat` and before `os.remove`. Moving all of the code raising errors to `try` / `except` should do the job. However, as I understand there is a problem with logging a truthful message. Additional flag `attempted_delete` should help with that:

```
attempted_delete = False
try:
    if os.stat(filename).st_mtime < current_time - 14 * 86400:
         os.remove(filename)
         count += 1
         attempted_delete = True
except:
     if attempted_delete:
         logger.warning("Not able to delete the file %s" % filename)
```

Comment: it will fail if two hosts chekc at same time, both will find file exists but both cant delete them.

Comment: @Rishi Bansal: I believe this is exactly what I wrote.

Answer (score 1):

An `except` clause with no exception (type) list is a catch-all: easy to setup but hard to use. Here you should specifically catch (and ignore) a `FileNotFoundError` and log any other exception:

```
try:
   if os.stat(filename).st_mtime < current_time - 14 * 86400:
      os.remove(filename)
      count += 1
except FileNotFoundError:
   pass  # file has already been deleted: all is fine
except:
   logger.warning("Not able to delete the file %s" % filename)
```

---

Above was for Python 3, as you use Python 2, you can only check for OSError and then control its errno attribute:

```
try:
   if os.stat(filename).st_mtime < current_time - 14 * 86400:
      os.remove(filename)
      count += 1
except OSError as e:
   if e.errno != errno.ENOENT:
      # do not log if file has already been deleted
      logger.warning("Not able to delete the file %s" % filename)
except:
   logger.warning("Not able to delete the file %s" % filename)
```

Comment: can you please give a working code, its giving error "NameError: name 'FileNotFoundError' is not defined".

Comment: @RishiBansal: I cannot help you. `FileNotFoundError` is a built in exception, a subclass of `OSError`. It is weird that you get `"NameError: name 'FileNotFoundError' is not defined"`. What is you OS and Python version?

Comment: @serve Python 2.6.6, redhat 6. If I use OSError it is catching both condition file not exist as well as if permission not there.

Comment: According to this [reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/learnpython/comments/7p637s/nameerror_name_filenotfounderror_is_not_defined/) which was the first thing I found on Googling your error, `FileNotFoundError` is only on Python3. You can use IOError instead, or run Python3. [This SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21367320/searching-for-equivalent-of-filenotfounderror-in-python-2) mentions other ways that might work with both Python 2 and 3.

Comment: @RishiBansal: It is also possible in Python 2, see my edit.

Comment: @SergeBallesta error -> AttributeError: 'exceptions.OSError' object has no attribute 'error'

Comment: @RishiBansal: it was a typo. The attribute is `errno` and not `error`. Post edited.

Comment: @SergeBallesta sorry, looks like issue with errno.ENOENT as well. If you can explain a bit may i will try to correct it from my side as well.

Comment: @RishiBansal: You need an `import errno` statement.

Comment: @SergeBallesta thanks for all your effort, it works.